# Loading Images into Java

Tags: java, image, swing, loading

I've just started programming in java. Recently, however, I haven't been able to load images into my games.

I've tried loading them into a separate resource package and read/watched countless tutorials, but nothing seems to be working at all!

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code or provide any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

Image dbImage;
Graphics dbg;

//Variables for screen size
int
GWIDTH = 800,
GHEIGHT = 500;

//Dimension of gwidth and gheight
Dimension screenSize = new Dimension (GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);

public Main (){
//constructor to spawn window
this.setTitle ("Pond");
this.setSize(screenSize);
this.setResizable(false);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
this.addKeyListener(new AL ());
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/resources/ninja-png.gif"));

}

 public static void main (String[] args){

 Main m = new Main ();
 }

 //Double Buffering
  @Override

   public void paint (Graphics g){

dbImage = createImage (getWidth(), getHeight());
dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();
draw (dbg);
g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);  

 }

 public void draw (Graphics g){
 }
 public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
 }
 //Event Listener Class
 public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
@Override
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
}
@Override
public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e){
 }
 }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code or provide any suggestions?"

1. Don't paint on top-level containers like `JFrame`.
2. Instead use a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method and call `super.paintComponent`
3. `@Override` `getPreferredSize()` on `JPanel` when painting, so the panel will have a preffered size.
4. Call `frame.pack()` instead of setting the size, and the preferred size of the `JPanel` will be respected.
5. Add that custom painting panel to the `JFrame`.
6. You never initialized the image you were trying to paint. Do this instead.

   ```
   dbImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png")).getImage();
   ```

   of declaring a new `ImageIcon` that you never use.
7. Run Swing apps from the [**Event Dispatch Thread**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like this

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Main m = new Main();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
8. Makes sure you have a resources package directly in the src

   ```
   Project
         src
            resources
   ```

---

[image]

Full refactored source code with *all* above mentioned things.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    Image dbImage;

    int GWIDTH = 800;
    int GHEIGHT = 500;

    public Main() {
        dbImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png")).getImage();
        this.setTitle("Pond");
        add(new ImagePanel());
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main m = new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, GWIDTH, GHEIGHT, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions, and made some changes for my game. It worked very well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I belive there is a simpler way:
Create a JLabel and add it to the frame:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(/*This uses a URL*/new URL(YOURURLHERE));
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(bi);
JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
```

Then just add that label to the frame.